# Web chart for "tons" of points?

Tags: c#, jquery, silverlight, flash, charts

I would like to know if is there some good web solutions to show charts for "huge data sets", I've tried amcharts and Highcharts Stock (jquery solutions) without success.

At the beginning they were working, but at the moment the "chrome" is telling me that the javascript memory is full and the page crashes.

I've times where I need to show more than 20 lines, each one with more than 100.000 points, so in the end I can have gigantic jquery arrays that sure will crash the internet browser.

At the moment I am open to change to some flash, silverlight or other solution (not java applet because I am using C#).

What do you guys recommend?

**UPDATE #1**

For example: one purpose of this application is to see ECG channels.
The person will carry a device with several "sensors" (lets define 10 or 12, more or less), the device will save the data each second (or sometimes even in shorter intervals). And there can be cases that the person will use this system for 3 days).

Minimum data: 
60 seconds * 60 minutes * 24 hours * 3 days = 259.200 points per line.
8 lines or more => 2.073.600 total points

Usability: 
Well, in this health area normally the "readings" will be similar, no highs or lows enough to be recognized in a 3 days data. So for this example the best would be to load the data just when it is needed > the pan/zoom slide is showing just 1hour and when it moves to other, then AJAX get the rest of the DATA. Sure this is the way to go. BUT this is not the only case in my system.

I've other type or devices where the "highs and lows" are HUGE and the user would like to see ALL data in just one "chart" without zoom in. So, in this situations just from a simple look it is easy to see that something happened on the readings, then the user can make zoom in and since the data is already on memory no need to make more AJAX calls and refresh the chart.

Smart way to go: process the data in a way to do "reduce" the number of points when we are looking at a bigger "scale". Sure, this is the wise way to go, but once again, there are times when the result of some processing math will "fake" and hide the real readings and in the end there are some "behaviors" that will not show up on the chart.

So, for now I really need to find a way to display all of this points.

Note: I really appreciate all the feedback of you guys.

Comment: Do you really need to show so many points in your graph? An approach might be to normalise your data in some way to remove some of the points in between, flash will have no problem handling the amount of data but you may still have rendering issues if you are trying to create so many points if they are very close together.

Comment: For now I really need to show this large amount of points :( I am not happy about it neither.....

Comment: Well I have had success drawing gps tracklogs using the line drawing api in flash, but I only got up to maybe about 5 or 10,000 points. AS3 has a pretty solid drawing api. I guess it depends on how complex your chart is, have you looked in to Flex as there are 3rd party chart solutions out there that may be right for you.

Comment: you can try pivot viewer for silverlight: http://www.silverlight.net/learn/data-networking/pivot-viewer/pivotviewer-control

Comment: Flash Player should be able to handle that. Still, which js, I'm not sure if you can do something like: 1. create a canvas to draw into; 2. load a chunk of data; parse it; draw onto the canvas; release/clear/null the parsed data. 3. move to a new chunk of data and repeat 2; 4. after all data has been processed and drawn into the canvas, display the canvas;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I'm with Neil here...there must be some way that this data can be processed before display...I mean, how can this amount of data even be displayed in a window?  You say a line has 100000 points...if each of those points was unique in the X,Y plane, 100000 points would completely fill a 300x300 display window.  20 lines like this would completely saturate a normal 1024x1280 display.

Presumably, that can't be what you are looking for, so I'm assuming there must be a lot of cases where the points overlap.  Preprocessing the data, to eliminate duplicate data points would help reduce the data size considerably.

It's hard to know exactly how this answer fits, or to give more precise instructions without further details, but if you have questions or clarifications, edit your question and I'll modify my answer (or delete it, if I've misinterpreted.)

**Response to Edit 1:**

I think that the way to approach the thinking for this is to recognize that for any given view, you can only show as many data points as you have horizontal resolution, so you can limit your data download to that.

From what I'm hearing (and I grant that I have *very* few details) this problem can be reduced to:

- Figuring out how many points to get (based on horizontal resolution)
- Calculating those points based on the data, horizontal scroll, zoom, and any heuristics.
- Dynamically downloading that data

That sounds not too bad, and your original problem (of too much data crashing the system) disappears.  That leaves you with secondary problem of how to calculate the height of the downloaded data.

> I've other type or devices where the "highs and lows" are HUGE and the
>   user would like to see ALL data in just one "chart" without zoom in.
>   So, in this situations just from a simple look it is easy to see that
>   something happened on the readings...

There are a number of potential difficulties that I can see here...

If the timescale for these events is too short, they won't be visible on a naively drawn graph.  If you have 100000 points in a particular line graph and your default viewing area is 1000 pixels wide with no zooming, you're only seeing 1 out of 100 datapoints.  If some spike lasts for 10 of the datapoints, for example, unless you do something special, there's a good chance it won't be visible on the graph (so the user won't know to "zoom in" for more resolution).  And how do you determine the height at which to plot the point?  The actual datapoint at a specific spot?  An average of the 100 data points that pixel covers?  A rolling average?  If don't average, you could miss spikes entirely.  If you do average, you could lower the amplitude of the spikes or troughs if they are of short duration.

This, I think (and, again, I'm doing a lot of guesswork) sounds like the real challenge.  Trying to find some way to display the graph which will definitely not be able to show all of the data at one time, but may be able to have some way to highlight points of interest dynamically (calculating, noting, and marking peaks and troughs with notations on the graph...things like that.)

Answer (score 0):

Try out the [Zoom Line chart](http://www.fusioncharts.com/demos/gallery/#zoom-line) from the FusionCharts stables.

I've myself created charts with 27,000 datapoints; and beyond the initial loading times, the chart worked smoothly.

Here is a blog post about the zoom line chart - http://blog.fusioncharts.com/2011/10/stuck-between-massive-historical-data-and-daily-intricacies-zoom-line-chart-to-the-rescue/

As a bonus, you can render the chart in pure JavaScript or Flash.

And it also works well with server-side languages. Check out their docs for more reading material - http://docs.fusioncharts.com/

Comment: He's looking to create charts with about 2 orders of magnitude more points than you tried. I'm not saying the system won't work (I haven't tried it)...but we're talking about a *lot* of data here, so even if the loading time scales linearly it's going to take him about 100 times as long to load. Since you were having trouble with loading times I'd be concerned that his loading times would be unacceptable (though he doesn't say what his parameters are...even though it's a web application, it may be that a long generation time is just fine.)